# Robocopy - Copy a single file from a directory and overwrite a file in a destination directory if its newer

Tags: robocopy

All, I've come across an issue with deploying a time sheet to users. I've researched robocopy a little bit and think it might be a solution.

I need to overwrite a copy of the time sheet located on the public desktop of each user every time I make changes to it. It has become a hassle navigating to each user's public desktop, primarily the ones connected through VPN on a poor connection.

Is there a way to copy the time sheet from a directory on a server and then overwrite the old copy on the users machine and attach it to a scheduled task so I don't have to reach out to each user every time I update the time sheet?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx This question doesn't show much research effort. You'll either learn how to make a simple batch script or pay a professional to do it for you! Link could be a good starting point, if you go for first option.

Comment: `Is there a way to copy the time sheet from a directory on a server and then overwrite the old copy on the users machine and attach it to a scheduled task so I don't have to reach out to each user every time I update the time sheet?` - I'm sure there is.

Answer (score 0):

okay, it was native windows administrator's concern day to day, however as per my understanding we should use the following to resolve this problem.

Before i answer, it mandatory to have the file only on the desktop or we can have a shortcut for that file on the desktop.

Place the file in a network drive. Map/share the network drive into all the users home directory or as separate drive, create logon batch script for the users in domain controller have it executed in whenever user logs into the systems. this batch should either copy the file from map drive to desktop or simply create shortcut to original file. it is my recommendation for this problem. we have fix the same kind of problem for builds not for excel or spreadsheet, so it should work.